# How does one think of $H_1$ with real or rational coefficients geometrically?

Tags: homology-cohomology

The title says it all. I'm still a beginner in homology, learning out of Hatcher, but I've run into mentions of $H_1$ with rational or real coefficients in some papers, and I'm struggling to see how that makes sense in the context of "cycles" in the graph-theoretic sense.

Comment: The short answer is that you are looking at cycles in the usual sense but with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R$ formally attached. I.e. there is no direct geometric meaning.

Comment: Jim, what's the long answer? Say in the case of the torus, with $H_1(\text{Torus};\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}^2$. I was thinking, perhaps, that we may be including *arcs* (or incomplete cycles, whatever that means) in our space. Maybe I'm overthinking this, but I like to hold on to an image when I think about this stuff.

Comment: I think it already makes no sense to hold on to a picture when the coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}$. As for "cycles", the terminology merely coincides here. (It is true that a cycle in a graph is also a cycle in the sense of homology. But what does a 2-cycle correspond to? It's better to think of them in terms of simplicial or cellular complexes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long answer is that for simply connected CW complexes $X$, one can construct another space, $X_{\mathbb Q}$ such that $\widetilde{H}_*(X;\mathbb Q)\cong \widetilde{H}_*(X_{\mathbb Q};\mathbb Z)$ and $\pi_*(X)\otimes\mathbb Q\cong \pi_*(X_{\mathbb Q})$. This construction is called the *rationalization* of $X$, and is a central construction in rational homotopy theory. (See p.108 of the book *Rational Homotopy Theory* by Felix, Halperin and Thomas.)

The most basic example is not simply connected but works anyway. It is formed by an infinite telescope, where you take infinitely many copies of $S^1\times I$ lined up in a row, where the left-hand circle from the $n$th copy is attached by wrapping it $n$ times around the right-hand circle of the $n-1$st copy. In other words, let the rational $1$-sphere $$S^1_{\mathbb Q}= (S^1\times I)\times \mathbb N/\sim$$ where $((\theta,0),n)\sim((n\theta,1),n-1)$. It is an interesting exercise to check that $\pi_1(S^1_{\mathbb Q})\cong \mathbb Q= \pi_1(S^1)\otimes\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Wow. Thank you, this is very nice. I'm guessing, then, it's hopeless to see a geometric picture for when the coefficients are in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Any topological space with $\pi_1(X)\cong\mathbb R$ would have to be pretty wild, since $\mathbb R$ is uncountable. Such spaces do exist, but I don't know that anybody has studied a functor along the lines of rationalization for $\mathbb R$.